# Store persistent data using javascript or other client side library

Tags: javascript, offline-caching

There is a way to write and get persistent data (i.e., that persists between page reloads and is accessible offline) in the browser using JavaScript or any client side language?

Comment: You mean like `localStorage`?

Comment: yes, could be it! If I exit the page then return the data will be there? I need this.. thank you!

Comment: Script on the page or as a plugin?

Comment: I will explain what I need to do and if you can you give me the best way, I have a offline app, that the user needs to login, I need a place to store the username and password, to the user login by javascript. In the online app version the user login using mysql and php.

Comment: Do not save credentials in local storage. Modern browser supply a password safe for users if the user wants to use it at all. A proper input tags will trigger that mechanism in browsers.

Comment: @CodeClown -- Good info, didn't know about this. Just posted an answer on localStorage, deleted :)

Comment: So, any hints how can I do this? is it possible?